# iOS swift URLScheme post silently without opening another app

Tags: ios, swift, url-scheme

Is there a way to send a data to another app using URLScheme without opening the other app? Once the data is received by the other app, data will be processed by the other app. Is this possible do this in iOS with swift?

Comment: No, there is not

Comment: Using url schemes you can open another app and pass data from one app to another but You can't do it SILENTLY as there is no api available to do the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do that using URLScheme.

If you are the owner/developer of both apps you can use the [App Groups](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_security_application-groups) to share data between these apps. One problem in this approach is your second app won't know when the data is being shared. To tackle this issue, you can use any of the following approach:

1. When user opens the app next time, check whether new data is available or not
2. Use a [Silent Push Notification](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_background_updates_to_your_app) to notify your second app when there is a change. For this to work, your first app needs to notify the server after sharing the data and your server needs to send the notification to your second app
3. Use [Background Fetch](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/scenes/preparing_your_ui_to_run_in_the_background/updating_your_app_with_background_app_refresh) API to launch your app in background and check for the shared data